# Has anyone used or tried connecting Amazon Alexa Echo Connect outside US?

Tags: android

A friend has gifted me an [Echo Connect](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076ZRFP6Y)  from US.

I am currently located in India and when I try connecting the Echo Connect device using the Alexa app on my android device, it doesn't display any option to connect.

Has any one tried to connect the device outside US, or is there any work around solution for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm in China, and I got an Echo Dot (3rd gen) from Australia, I was facing the same problem as you when I launch the application, I read that Amazon block the app if they detect your SIM card is in China, so I just put another sim card, and the app worked, now I have zero problem, I don't know if it's clear enough.